# Вывод строк из таблицы базы данных

Tags: python, база-данных, discord

Пишу бота в дискорде, который прибавляет очки по количеству сообщений от пользователей и начисляет уровень. С карточкой уровня справилась, хочу сделать карточку статистики из базы данных: id пользователя - уровень.

```
@bot.command()
async def top(ctx):
    async with bot.db.cursor() as cursor:
        await cursor.execute("SELECT level FROM levels ORDER BY level DESC")
        level = await cursor.fetchall()
        await cursor.execute("SELECT user FROM levels ORDER BY level DESC")
        name = await cursor.fetchall()
        for number in level:
            for i in number:
                print(i, ' ', end="")
            print('\n')
        for id in name:
            for k in id:
                print(k, ' ', end="")
            print('\n')
```

C частью вывода данных в столбик на консоль я справилась. Теперь мне нужно с помощью библиотеки easy-pil вывести точно так же на карточку со статистикой:

```
background = Editor(_image="backgroundleader.png")
        # profile_picture = await load_image_async(str(name.avatar.url))
        # profile = Editor(profile_picture).resize((50, 50)).circle_image()
        #
        # Закомментила, потому что пока не знаю, как через id из бд привязать аватар
        #
        # background.paste(profile, (50, 200))
        poppins_small = Font.poppins(size=20)
        background.text(
             (120, 215),
             f"{name}: level - {level}",
             font=poppins_small,
             color="#FFFFFF"
         )

         file = discord.File(fp=background.image_bytes, filename="leaderboard.png")
         await ctx.send(file=file)
```

На карточке получается только одна строка: [image: карточка leaderboard]

Как заменить print, чтобы цикл и вывод элементов был таким же как в консоли?